# Why is memory not freed when using threadpool::Threadpool in a loop?

Tags: multithreading, memory, rust, threadpool

I have a heavy multithreaded application using a threadpool and a large number of threads. Within a thread, it generates a rather big data structure (`Data`; 100 Bytes < `Data` < 1kb) which should be dropped after finishing the work. This, however, seems to be not the case, even if I manually drop it (`std::mem::drop`). So, I cannot use this algorithm because it hits my memory limit.

Why is the thread not freeing the memory?

What can I do to make the thread free the memory? If this is not possible, how can I modify the algorithm to make use of a big number of iterations?

```rust
use threadpool::ThreadPool; // 1.8.1

#[derive(Default)]
struct Data([u64; 32]);

fn main() {
    // In my case, this can be 7 to 31.
    let pool = ThreadPool::new(num_cpus::get() as usize - 1);

    for _ in 0..100_000_000 {
        pool.execute(move || {
            let mut t = vec![];
            for _ in 0..100 {
                t.push(Data::default());
            }
            std::mem::drop(t);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The value passed to Threadpool::new() is the number of CPUs minus one. In my case this can be 7 to 31. As I understood threadpools, I do not allocate N_CPUS * 100 * LENGTH_OF_TEXT concurrently. I was thinking, that the threads allocate thier memory once they start. And no, I do not have the memory.

Comment: If it is as you @Shepmaster say and the memory is allocated for each thread at once, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is the point of having a threadpool, if it allocates everything at once?

Comment: *As I understood threadpools [...] the threads allocate thier memory once they start* — yes, and you attempt to start `100_000_000` threads, so you will quickly start up all 31 threads.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by avoiding to queue too many tasks at once into the pool. For example, you can check [`Threadpool::queued_count`](https://docs.rs/threadpool/1.8.1/threadpool/struct.ThreadPool.html#method.queued_count) to make sure that you never queue more tasks than you have CPUs, along with a [`CondVar`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html) that you trigger at the beginning of each task to wake up the control thread when space becomes available in the queue:

```
use threadpool::ThreadPool; // 1.8.1

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, Condvar};

fn main() {
    // In my case, this can be 7 to 31.
    let pool = ThreadPool::new(num_cpus::get() as usize - 1);

    let cond = Arc::new((Mutex::new(()), Condvar::new()));
    
    for _ in 0..2_000 {
        let c = cond.clone();
        pool.execute(move || {
            {
                let (lock, cvar) = &*c;
                let _guard = lock.lock().unwrap();
                cvar.notify_one();
            }

            std::thread::sleep (std::time::Duration::from_millis (1));
        });
        /* Uncomment the following to keep the queue size down. */
        /*
        let (lock, cvar) = &*cond;
        let guard = lock.lock().unwrap();
        if pool.queued_count() >= num_cpus::get() {
            let _ = cvar.wait (guard).unwrap();
        }
        */
    }
    
    for l in BufReader::new (File::open ("/proc/self/status").unwrap()).lines().map (Result::unwrap) {
        if l.starts_with ("VmRSS") {
            println!("{}", l);
        }
    }

    pool.join();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=1fc2059fb83c5a1df76d92ceb0ac4b27)

Note: I'm keeping the number of tasks down to avoid a timeout in the playground. With the code as above, I get 2.5MB of memory used. If I uncomment the check on `queued_count`, memory use goes down to less than 1MB.

Comment: Thx, Jmb. The algorithm, however, is very slow. It seems only one cpu is used at a time.

Comment: Yet if you print a trace each time a thread starts/stops a task, you can see that they are distributed on the threads: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=eac58439c89bae583503aa142acf4030).

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem with a thread executor which sends threads to the threadpool only once another thread is finished, preventing sending all the threads to the queue at once.

The problem seems to be that the threadpool's queue is filled with threads at once although they are not executed. Thus, they fill the memory and crash the system. I did not expect that.

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::thread;
use threadpool::ThreadPool; // 1.8.1

#[derive(Default)]
struct Data([u64; 32]);

fn main() {
    let pool = ThreadPool::new(num_cpus::get() as usize - 1);

    let (tx, rx) = channel();
    let (tx_result, rx_result) = channel();

    // send initial threads
    let tx_ = tx.clone();
    for x in 0..num_cpus::get() {
        tx_.send(x);
    }

    // collect results
    thread::spawn(move || {
        while let Ok(r) = rx_result.recv() {
            println!(">>> Got result {}", r);
        }
    });

    let mut count = 10_000_000;
    while let Ok(_) = rx.recv() {
        if count < 0 {
            break;
        }

        let tx_ = tx.clone();
        let tx_result_ = tx_result.clone();

        pool.execute(move || {
            let mut t = vec![];
            for _ in 0..100 {
                t.push(Data::default());
            }
            tx_result_.send(count);
            tx_.send(1).unwrap();
        });

        count -= 1;
    }

    pool.join();

    std::mem::drop(tx);
    std::mem::drop(tx_result);
}
```